# Traefik ingress basic auth not authorized successfully

Tags: basic-authentication, traefik

Test traefik basic authentication by applying an authorize ingress toward pod=whoami (sample image in traefik official documentation), my yamls were provided as follows:

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: authsecret
  namespace: default
data:
  users: YWRtaW46JGFwcjEkcWE1VU9McWlBOE9rWklqQXpGZ0hOeXhGTTUxM3V3Z3R6RnNZMW5jZ0NoeW4=
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: whoami
  labels:
    app: whoami

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: traefik/whoami
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami

spec:
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: web

  selector:
    app: whoami
```

**Ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: authsecret
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-remove-header: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /whoami
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: whoami
            port:
              name: web
```

I wished to authorize by the secret with name=”authsecret”, which contains user name & password encoded by base64 encoder.

When I browse the webpage, I saw the login form and typed the username & password in decoded value respectively, but the prompt just keeps showing up, which indicates 401 unauthorized error, is there anything wrong with my setting?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUmlG.png)

[traefik](/questions/tagged/traefik) [ingress](/questions/tagged/ingress) [basic-auth](/questions/tagged/basic-auth)

Wish all kinds of suggestion.